# Can't make socket.io work on HTTPS connect

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, socket.io

Im tried to run my node server with https. I'm using express and socket.io.

I get err in my console "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

I have self-signed SSL.

The code works fine when run without SSL. I do not know if my signed certificate can be accepted.

Please show me how: 1. Accept the self-signed SSL certificate. or 2. Help me do this job differently.

node v6.16.0
server CentOS

This is my code for https:

```
//server-side

'use strict';

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();
var md5 = require('md5');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.com.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.com.crt', 'utf8'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

var io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('an user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

httpsServer.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3030');
});
```

Client's side

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>

</head>


<body>

<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>



<script src="/Assets/js/socket.io.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        var host = 'https://example.com:3030';
        var socket = io.connect(host, {secure: true});

        socket.on('connect', function(){
            socket.on('event', function(data){});
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
        });


        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: certs typically have to be from a valid body (ie GoDaddy) in order for them to work with things like nodejs, angular, etc

Comment: Agree with @mast3rd3mon, and I personally think its probably more frustrating to configure your system to support self-signed certs than to just use letsencrypt certbot or something similar (free). Also you may see sparse documentation on this because most people offload the SSL to a proxy like haproxy or nginx.

Comment: Guys, thank you. I buy new ssl-cert, and no more problems. Please, Everybody don't used self-signed cert SSL)

Comment: @Tihün: can you answer this if you resolved this? Are you using nginx?